# Why $S[x]/f(x)$ is used to denote a quotient ring of polynomials instead of $S[x]/f(x)S[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I'm a bit confused about the notation used for quotient rings.

In the notation for a quotient rings on both sides of the $/$ there is a set. More specifically a ring divided by one of it's ideals.

For arithmetic modulo integer $n$. We use the notation $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
Which looks ok to me.

But for arithmetic modulo some arbitrary polynomial $f(x)$ over some ring $S$ we use the notation $S[x]/f(x)$. There $f(x)$ just a single polynomial, not an ideal in itself. Syntax errors tingling in my brain when I see it. Why don't we write  $S[x]/f(x) S[x]$ instead?

Comment: Yeah, it's more properly $S[x]/f(x)S[x]$, or some indication that we are taking the quotient by the ideal generated by $f(x)$, like $S[x]/(f(x)),\ S[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$,...

Comment: Do we? Surely we use $S[x]/(f(x))$ or $S[x]/\left<f(x)\right>$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So the extra parenthesis imply the ideal?

Comment: Also note that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is occasionally found.

Comment: @Calmarius Yes, so for instance we also have $\Bbb Z[x]/(3,x^2+1)$ etc.